# How to set page size/default zoom in Magento 2.1.5

Tags: magento-2.1, zoom

I bought a theme and I was wondering if there is any way that I could change/modify the theme default page zoom/size ? If I scale it down in my browser to 80% it looks way better and I would like it to be the default view for visitors. Is there any way that I could do this ? Im using Magento 2.1.5. Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks, Denis A.

Answer (score 0):

** Go to \vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\etc\view.xml**

```
 You can enable the magnifier ‘true’
```

```
<var name="magnifier">
<var name="fullscreenzoom">5</var> <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
<var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
<var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
<var name="width"></var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
<var name="height"></var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
<var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that activates zoom (hover/click) -->
<var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (zoom) (true/false) -->
</var>
```